# Яка різниця між відмінюванням у родовому відмінку слів "детектив" (як людина) та "детектив" (як літературний жанр)?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, стилістика

Яка різниця між відмінюванням слів "детектив" (як людина) та "детектив" (як літературний жанр)?

Answer (score 1):

[Словники української мови](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2) дають таку інформацію:

У множині відмінність тільки у знахідному відмінку, для людини закінчення: *-ів*; для жанру: *-и*.

В однині:

1. У родовому відмінку для людини перевага надається відмінюванню з закінченням *-а*; для жанру — *-у*.
2. У давальному відмінку для людини: *-ові*; для жанру: *-у*.
3. У знахідному відмінку для людини: *-а*; для жанру: нульове закінчення.
4. У місцевому відмінку для людини: *-ові*; для жанру: *-і*.
   [image]